# ZSH autocomplete

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

How do I make zsh give me the autcomplete options but not fill in the prompt line with the first result? For example, this is the behavior I'm seeing:

```
$ ifc{tab}
```

```
$ ifcfg
external command
ifcfg     ifconfig
```

I want it to display the options, but not fill in the prompt line.

Also, if I type in a valid command, but there are other valid commands that start with that, it doesn't auto complete. So

```
su{tab}
```

will give me just `su` instead of the option for `sudo`

Comment: I think the default behavior conforms to your requirement. What completion options have you set?

Comment: I copied an zshrc file from the web and I'm wondering what options cause this to be different. I can post the zshrc file if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsetopt automenu
```

from `man zshoptions`:

> **AUTO_MENU**
>
> Automatically  use  menu completion after the second consecutive request for completion, for example  by  pressing  the  tab  key repeatedly. This option is overridden by **MENU_COMPLETE**.

Comment: So is it not possible to use menu_complete, but not make it fill in the text on the prompt line?